# Clojure: lein task cannot find jdbc, even though application can find it fine

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to make a custom lein task called migrate, so I can say on the command line:

```
lein migrate
```

lein finds my task file under src/leiningen/migrate.clj (as per the leiningen convention).  In the ns declaration for the task I have a require for a file from my project

```
(ns leiningen.migrate
  (require [triface.migration :as mm]))

(defn migrate []
  (mm/run-migrations))
```

It finds src/triface/migration.clj fine, but THAT file requires a file that requires jdbc:

```
(ns triface.db
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))
```

This call works fine in my application, but from this lein task it fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc.clj on classpath
```

What is going on here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath is slightly different.
To use it as is, you must define :dev-dependencies in your project.clj file.

For example,

```
:dev-dependencies [[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.0.4"] ]
```

Then, the jar file is loaded properly.

```
(ns triface.migration
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))

 (defn run-migrations[]
   "hello")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see how Lein-LB does it here: https://bitbucket.org/kumarshantanu/lein-lb/src/tip/README.md

*Edit:* Fixed the URL